# MySQL DELETE OR SELECT AND DELETE

Tags: mysql

Who is better ? Delete or select and delete if exist.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 1;

OR

SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1;

// IF ROW COUNT == 1

DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 1;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to delete one row, then you can use `limit`:

```
DELETE FROM users
WHERE id = 1
LIMIT 1;
```

However, `id` is probably already unique in the table.  The query without `LIMIT` will delete all matching rows.  If there are none, no rows are deleted -- there is no error.

Answer (score 2):

No need to check if row exists first with a SELECT, that's what the WHERE clause does on your DELETE. If you intend on deleting all rows, TRUNCATE is generally more efficient than DELETE, however you will not be able to roll the operation back, since the saving to undo space is bypassed.